# How to get object inside another object in JQuery

Tags: jquery, bootbox

How can i get the li that i clicked inside `bootbox.confirm()`?

```
<ul id="something">
  <li>Result 1</li>
  <li>Result 2</li>
  <li>Result 3</li>
</ul>

$('#something li').click(function(){
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if(result == true){
        alert("You deleted" + /*here I want to get the item that was clicked*/);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cache the context with `this`:

```
$('#something li').click(function(){
    var $this = this; // cache it here
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if(result == true){
           alert("You deleted" + $this.textContent/*use it here now!!*/);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$( this )` in this context.

```
$('#something li').click(function(){
    console.log($( this ));
});
```

See: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I want to use it inside the bootbox.confirm function and $(this) gets the context of the confirm function

Comment: Oh, I see, than Jai's answer will be perfect for you.